# How to draw a route between many geo points in google map (note: this is a bus stop route line)?

Tags: android, google-maps

[This is my image.Wrong route.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DiDhm.png)
[I want to this route like that.Correct route.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJGzB.png)

I have many many static geo points for geo point for bus stops.Sometime geo points exist over hundred.I can route using polyline but that show me straight line.I want to see road line.

I tried and looking for many question but only see between two points.I have been tried using roads api from google.But this is limit just 100 points.So i cann't use roads api.Please point me.

```
public void getBusStopInfo() {
    HttpService httpService = NetManager.getInstance().create(HttpService.class);
    Observable<GdResultData> observable = httpService.findByRoute(id);
    RxManager.getInstance().getHttpListResult(observable, newRxSubscriber<GdResultBean<List<BusStopServerBean>>>(getContext()) {
        @Override
        protected void _onError(Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (mLoadingDialog != null) {
                mLoadingDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void _onNext(GdResultBean<List<BusStopServerBean>>listGdResultBean) {
            if (listGdResultBean.getErrorID() != HttpFields.HTTP_RESULT_OK) {
                return;
            }
            List<BusStopServerBean> object = listGdResultBean.getObject();
            for (BusStopServerBean busStopServerBean : object) {
                if (isMmLanguage) {
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(busStopServerBean.getLat(), busStopServerBean.getLng()))
                           .title(busStopServerBean.getNameMm()).snippet(busStopServerBean.getRoadMm())
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.bus_stop_circler)).alpha(0.9f).flat(true))
                            .setTag(busStopServerBean.getId());
                } else {
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(busStopServerBean.getLat(), busStopServerBean.getLng()))
                            .title(busStopServerBean.getNameEn()).snippet(busStopServerBean
                                   .getRoadEn()).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.mipmap.bus_stop_circler))
                           .alpha(0.9f).flat(true)).setTag(busStopServerBean.getId());
                }
            }
            insertBusLine(object);
            mLoadingDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }, BusStopServerBean.class);
}



private void insertBusLine(List<BusStopServerBean> object) {
    if (object == null || object.size() == 0) {
        return;
    }
    LatLngBounds.Builder boundBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    LatLng latLng;

//This is for route
    PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions()
            .color(Color.parseColor(color))
            .geodesic(false)
            .width(5);

    //this is for geo points latlng over 100 obj size
    for (BusStopServerBean busStopServerBean : object) {
        latLng = new LatLng(busStopServerBean.getLat(), busStopServerBean.getLng());busStopServerBean.getLng()));
        polylineOptions.add(latLng);
        boundBuilder.include(latLng);
    }


    mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);//this is show route on map[enter image description here][1]
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(boundBuilder.build(), 11));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each route with multiple waypoints consists of routes between two waypoints. So, taking into account the [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints):

> **Caution:** Queries using 10 or more waypoints or waypoints
>   Optimization, paid at a higher rate. Learn more about invoicing
>   for the Google Maps Platform products.

you can split your single request with more than 100 waypoints into multiple requests with less than 10 waypoints (and even run them in parallel) and combine its results to get the entire route.

Comment: @HZan Yes, there is no other way. But you should split single request with many waypoints to multiply requests with no more than 10 waypoints. Also take a look at [Snap to Roads](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/snap) from [Roads API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/intro).

Comment: I was tested by roads api but my route is straight and this is limit 100 point.If i add 100 points over that is error.

Comment: @HZan Just create 10 requests with 10 points, not one with 100.

Comment: Do you have any sample or tutorial.